# Haskell custom isordered function to check a list of integers

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to write a Haskell function that checks if a list of integers is in order without using any of the already existing functions to order or check the order of the list. I have written the following code but I do not understand why it does not work. I get the error:

```
No instance for (Ord integer)
      arising from a use of `<='
    In the expression: x <= (head xs)
```

I don't understand what this means. Is there a different way that I should be writing this function? Here is my code so far.

```
isordered :: [integer] -> Bool
isordered [] = True
isordered (x:[]) = True
isordered (x:xs)|x <= (head xs) = isordered xs
                |otherwise = False
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It should be `Integer`, not `integer`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell type names start with capital letters and type variables start with lower case letters. So if you write `integer`, that's a type variable. So your type is the same as `[a] -> Bool`, i.e. you take a list of anything and return a Bool. So since there's no restriction on what type of item might be in the list, you're not allowed to use `<=` on it.

To fix this you can either just change it to `Integer`, which is what you wanted, or add an Ord constraint like this: `Ord a => [a] -> Bool`. The latter will make your function work with any type that implements the `Ord` typeclass (which provides the comparison operators such as `<=`).

Answer (score 3):

What exactly counts as "already existing function"?

```
isordered xs = all (uncurry (<=)) $ zip xs (tail xs)
```

More low-level is

```
isordered (x:y:zs) = x <= y && isordered (y:zs)
isordered _ = True
```

Comment: Any existing library functions that involve sorting or ordering would have been a better thing to say! In your more low level function there will that not always return true?

Comment: I would write that : `isOrdered xs = and $ zipWith (<=) xs tail xs` to avoid that uncurry.

Comment: @chefburns: No, but try it out.

Comment: @Felix: I think you could replaced the `tail xs` with `drop 1 xs` to make it save for empty lists (didn't try it, though)

Answer (score 0):

Another way for doing it using guards:

```
isOrdered :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
isOrdered (x:y:xs) | x<=y = isOrdered (y:xs)
                   | otherwise = False
isOrdered _ = True
```